# C++ - Storing a BLOB as a string

Tags: c++, encoding, blob

Is it OK to store a BLOB as a string in C++? I'm guessing there could be a null character within the BLOB which could cause std::string operations like len() to fail. I'm trying to store a bitmap as a BLOB.

Eventually I want to store this string into an embedded database and read the string back into std::string

Thanks.

Comment: Embedded nulls are fine. Just don't use `C` string functions on it.  size/length do not depend on the contents.

Comment: When you say "store", do you mean representation in memory, or saving to a file on disk?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `std::string` objects are agnostic of the actual data being stored, and only append a `null` character to the end of the data as a compatibility thing with c-strings. As a general principle, if I'm storing raw data, I prefer to use `std::vector<int8_t>` (or `std::vector<uint8_t>`), since it more accurately expresses *intent* but in terms of data integrity, there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: What would you construct the `std::string` from? If your source is a `char*`, the `std::string` constructor would stop copying at a null character.

Comment: ^I would just append characters representing each 8 byte.

Comment: @Fred std::string has a constructor that takes a char * and a length as parameters for just this case,

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Yes, I was about to edit my comment to mention that.

Comment: You could also consider `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine. The `std::string` must store the length separately, so it can have embedded null characters. As long as you have enough memory for it, you can store it in a string.

You do need to be careful about constructing the string, though. If you just used somethnig like `std::string s = "Hello,\0 world!"`, this would not work, because converting from a `char*` only goes to the first null character. However, `std::string s("Hello,\0 world!", 14);` works fine.

Of course, if you do convert back to a `char*` with `data()` or `c_str()`, you need to make sure you also grab the length.